# with Flatlists renderItem in react native, if I use the value of Item as an index of an array, it is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, lodash, react-native-flatlist

when accessing the `item` passed to `_renderItem`, I can use the value like so `<Text>{item.item}</Text>` and it prints 1, 2, but cannot use it as an index for an array like this `<Text>{get(GLOBAL, ['products', 'item.item', 'title'], '')}</Text>` where this returns an empty string.

```
import get from 'lodash.get';

~~~

_renderItem = (item) => {

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>{item.item}</Text>
            <Text>{get(GLOBAL, ['products', 'item.item', 'title'], '')}</Text>
        </View >
    )
};

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.list}>
            <FlatList
                data={[1,2]}
                renderItem={this._renderItem} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

`<Text>{get(GLOBAL, ['products', 'item.item', 'title'], '')}</Text>` this outputs `''` but `<Text>{get(GLOBAL, ['products', '1', 'title'], '')}</Text>` outputs as expected.

how-come these respond differently and how could I use the value passed in `item` to `_renderItem` as the index of an array?

the reason for this is that the data passed to the FlatList corresponds to the index of the product that I want to fetch certain information from.

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the item value and instead of the object and property, you're passing a string as a parameter for concating the `lodash.get` object. Try to do it like this:

```js
_renderItem = (item) => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>{item.item}</Text>
            <Text>{get(GLOBAL, ['products', item.item, 'title'], '')}</Text>
        </View >
    )
};
```

That will actually get `GLOBAL['products'][1]['title']` when the item is `1` instead of `GLOBAL['products']['item.item']['title']` that you're having now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget is: `_renderItem = ({item})` not `_renderItem = (item)`

Comment: I've tried both and still having the same issue that I cant use the value for an array index like `arr[item]`. if it cant be done it cant be done i'm probably just overlooking something

Comment: He is doing `item.item` so that's not the issue here.